# Display.getRotation() not exactly working for 180 degree flips of the device

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I'm using Display.getRotation() and simply displaying the rotation with a toast message in my onCreate() method since onCreate() is called every time you rotate the screen.

Anyway, I discovered some odd behaviour which I think is best explained with an example.

Let's say I'm holding the device in it's "natural" rotation of 0 degrees. If I rotate 90 degrees clock wise I get 270 degrees, and if I rotate 90 degrees counter-clock wise I get 90 degrees. However, if I quickly rotate the device 180 degrees, that is fast enough so that there is no transition through the 90 degree rotation, or the 270 degree rotation, the entire image does get rotated, but the rotation still gets reported as the original 0 degrees.

Let's say I were holding at 90 degrees, it works just fine if I rotate 90 degrees in either direction, but if I do the 180 degree flip, again, the image rotates, but it still reports the original 90 degrees.

What's the deal here? Any ideas?

I'm going to try some more experimentation, if I figure it out, I'll post up the results.

Comment: So it seems that onCreate() or even onResume() isn't executed when I do the 180 flip. So perhaps this isn't the proper way for app to detect a rotation. Anyone know if there's some sort of "onRotate" listener I could use?

Comment: Hi,Andi jay.I am facing same problem when i turn device quickly.plz tell me how to detect sudden 180 degree turn.thanks

Comment: I was never able to figure out a way to detect that. Sorry buddy. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html):

```
public int getRotation ()
```

Since: API Level 8
Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation. The returned value may be Surface.ROTATION_0 (no rotation), Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, or Surface.ROTATION_270. For example, if a device has a naturally tall screen, and the user has turned it on its side to go into a landscape orientation, the value returned here may be either Surface.ROTATION_90 or Surface.ROTATION_270 depending on the direction it was turned. The angle is the rotation of the drawn graphics on the screen, which is the opposite direction of the physical rotation of the device. For example, if the device is rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise, to compensate rendering will be rotated by 90 degrees clockwise and thus the returned value here will be Surface.ROTATION_90.

I hope this clarifies some things for you.

Answer (score 0):

so... i seem to have this issue on HTC one, running cyanogenmod.
answer above doesn't seem to answer this question, but maybe i'm just missing it.

i solved with orientationEventListener while also using onresume and Display.getRotation() to track orientation (i'm using this to set exif rotation data in image files).

in onResume i do:

```
if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){  // portrait
    mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
}else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270){ // CW 90
    mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
}else if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){  // portrait inverted
    mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
}else{ // CW 270
    mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
}
```

in onCreate i setup an orientationEventListener that implements onOrientationChange:

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(
        context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            if (orientation >= 315 && orientation < 45) {  // portrait upright
                mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
            } else if (orientation >= 45 && orientation < 135) {  // CW 90
                mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
            } else if (orientation >= 135 && orientation < 225) { // portrait upside down
                // FIXME: this one is also 270??  display.getrotation is broken at least...
                mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
            } else if (orientation >= 225 && orientation < 315) {
                mPicOrientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
            }

        //Log.d(picGlobals.TAG, "orientation: " + orientation + " surface_rotation: " + mPicOrientation);
    }
};
if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
    mOrientationEventListener.enable();
}
```

the resultant rotation required on the pics is non-sensical with portrait inverted orientation.  i have no idea why.  it might be the few devices i tested on.
i'll test again in the emulator, but it's really really hard to tell when its emulated camera pictures are upside down (thanks google).
it works *most* of the time when portrait inverted.  but not all the time.  drives me nuts, but who really wants to take pics that way anyway?
orientationEventListener works everytime.  but it's of course not triggered until you actually change orientations (not sure what the threshold is).  that's why i have the Display.getRotation() in onResume.